# How to work unbound in VS2008 when the solution is

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, sourcegear-vault

Scenario:

- Solution is bound
- The team prefers to work bound
- I want to work unbound.  To that end, in Tools/Options/Source Control I set the current source control plug-in to None.

However, when I load the solution, VS2008 switches the source control plugin on and binds all the files.

How can I turn off the source control bindings for good in VS2008?

Comment: Why do you want to work unbound?

Comment: Why? The solution starts up massively faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File->Source Control->Change Source Control. Select all projects and the solution and click "Unbind".

But really... why would you want to abandon source control, especially when the rest of the team uses it? It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: I'll use source control from the separate SCC IDE

Comment: u could save a private copy of the solution and never check it back in, so a new version wouldn't force you to redo the above step. .sln merging is not nice, however.